# how to apply styles for parentItem when select the sub Item in the kendo menu

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Menu, I am trying to apply styles for selected item in the menu. I have implemented like

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    select: function (e) {
        // Remove previously selected options for this menu
        $(".k-state-selected", this.element).removeClass("k-state-selected");
        // Select item
        $(e.item).addClass("k-state-selected")
    }
});

.k-menu .k-state-selected> .k-link {
    color: lightcoral;
}
```

with the above,I am able to apply styles for selected Item in the menu.

now,

I have sub items in the each parent item,when I select sub item in the menu,I want to apply this styles to the parent Item.can any one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *play* with the styling to the node that you select (similar to what you do with the selected item), you should know that those nodes are marked with the CSS class `k-state-active`.

Then what I propose is:

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    select: function (e) {
        // Remove previously selected options for this menu
        $(".k-state-selected", this.element).removeClass("k-state-selected");
        $(".ob-selected-ancestor").removeClass("ob-selected-ancestor");

        // Select item
        $(e.item).addClass("k-state-selected")
        $(".k-state-active", this.element).addClass("ob-selected-ancestor");
    }
});
```

Where I start removing the style that I use `ob-selected_ancestor` from any marked node (clean everything before starting).

Then what I do is add this CSS class ( `ob-selected-ancestor`) to every node that has `k-state-active`.

Finally define this style, for example:

```
.ob-selected-ancestor {
    color: green;
}
```